# My PHP code not working with PHP 7.1 or 7.2

Tags: php, whmcs

I have small issue with php coding for newest php version, the original code:

```
<?php

function smarty_function_gravatar($params, &$smarty) {

    $email = (isset($params['email']) ? trim(strtolower($params['email'])) : '');
    $rating = (isset($params['rating']) ? $params['rating'] : 'R');
    $url = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/".md5($email) . "?r=".$rating;

    if(isset($params['default']))
        $url .= "&d=".urlencode($params['default']);
    if(isset($params['size']))
        $url .= "&s=".$params['size'];

    if(isset($params['assign'])) {
        $smarty->assign($params['assign'], $url);
        return;
    }

    return $url;
}

add_hook('ClientAreaPage', 1, 'smarty_function_gravatar');
```

From error logs:

```
{main} {"exception":"[object] (ArgumentCountError(code: 0): Too few arguments to function smarty_function_gravatar(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected at /home/myuser/public_html/includes/hooks/avatar.php:3)"} []
```

Please help to replace new code for php 7.2

Comment: It says in your error you pass few arguements to your function called `smarty_function_gravatar`

Comment: That hook isn't sending the right parameters for that function

Answer (score 1):

I can only suggest the following, I have never used whmcs before, but its possible that the `global $smarty;` variable can been referenced instead.

change

```
function smarty_function_gravatar($params, &$smarty) {
```

to

```
function smarty_function_gravatar($params){
global $smarty;
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, please if my answer has helped, accept it as your answer to the question.