# Small PHP error Too few arguments to function on php72

Tags: php, smarty, php-7.1, whmcs, php-7.2

I need help fixing a small problem with my php script to work on php7.2, the code below works on php7.0 but doesn't work on php7.1 or 7.2 :(

Error showing on debug:

```
    ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function smarty_function_gravatar(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected in public_html/includes/hooks/custom-function.php: Line 91


Stack trace:
    #0 /public_html/includes/hookfunctions.php(0): smarty_function_gravatar(Array)
    #1 /public_html/includes/clientareafunctions.php(0): run_hook('ClientAreaPage', Array)
    #2 /public_html/login.php(0): outputClientArea('login', false, Array)
    #3 /public_html/member/viewticket.php(0): unknown()
    #4 {main}
```

My original code on line 91:

```
 function smarty_function_gravatar($params, &$smarty) {
    $email = (isset($params['email']) ? trim(strtolower($params['email'])) : '');
    $rating = (isset($params['rating']) ? $params['rating'] : 'R');
    $url = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/".md5($email) . "?r=".$rating;

    if(isset($params['default']))
        $url .= "&d=".urlencode($params['default']);
    if(isset($params['size']))
        $url .= "&s=".$params['size'];

    if(isset($params['assign'])) {
        $smarty->assign($params['assign'], $url);
        return;
    }
    return $url;
 }
```

---

On template .tpl

```
<img src="{gravatar email="{if $reply.name eq 'Admin 1'}admin1@domain.com{elseif $reply.name eq 'Admin 2'}admin2@domain.com{elseif $reply.name eq 'Admin 3'}admin3@domain.com{elseif $reply.name eq 'Admin 4'}admin4@domain.com{/if}" size="140"}" height="60" width="60">

{elseif $reply.contactid} <img src="{gravatar email="$replyemail" size="140"}" height="60" width="60">

{elseif $reply.userid} 
<img src="{gravatar email="$replyemail" size="140" default="/default-avatar.png"}" height="60" width="60">
{else} 
<img src="{gravatar email="$replyemail" size="140" default="/default-avatar.png"}" height="60" width="60">
```

Comment: How many params are you passing to `smarty_function_gravatar()`? The message suggests either 0 or 1 rather than 2.

Comment: `1 passed and exactly 2 expected`  One...  I think the error is pretty clear.

Comment: @ggdx i have update the post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My PHP code not working with PHP 7.1 or 7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49642149/my-php-code-not-working-with-php-7-1-or-7-2)

Answer (score 6):

Missing arguments would only trigger a warning until PHP/7.0 but since PHP/7.1 they throw a fatal error ([demo](https://3v4l.org/1cuZT)). From [7.0 migration guide](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php):

> Previously, a warning would be emitted for invoking user-defined functions with too few arguments. Now, this warning has been promoted to an Error exception. This change only applies to user-defined functions, not internal functions.

Chances are that it never really worked but you've configured PHP to hide error information—something that's no longer useful with fatal errors because they abort execution anyway.

Since you never use the function's second argument, just get rid of it entirely.

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand, whether you give a suggestion to delete code or add code

Comment: Please check Martin's answer. I presume it isn't a custom function but a Twig plugin of some kind that was designed for an older version.

Answer (score 4):

see [kevinpapst.de](https://www.kevinpapst.de/blog/gravatar-smarty-tag.html) (in German); it's from 2008 and so is the syntax ...

meanwhile the [documentation](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.writing.tpl) says something else about "Writing Plugins":

> As a general rule, the currently evaluated template's `Smarty_Internal_Template` object is always passed to the plugins as the last parameter with two exceptions:

- modifiers do not get passed the `Smarty_Internal_Template` object at all.
- blocks get passed $repeat after the `Smarty_Internal_Template` object to keep backwards compatibility to older versions of Smarty.

for example:

```
function smarty_function_gravatar(array $params, Smarty_Internal_Template $template) {

    $email = (isset($params['email']) ? trim(strtolower($params['email'])) : '');
    $rating = (isset($params['rating']) ? $params['rating'] : 'R');

    $url = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/".md5($email) . "?r=".$rating;
    if(isset($params['default'])) {
        $url .= "&d=".urlencode($params['default']);
    }
    if(isset($params['size'])) {
        $url .= "&s=".$params['size'];
    }
    if(isset($params['assign'])) {
        $template->smarty->assign($params['assign'], $url);
        return;
    }
    return $url;
}
```

to be used alike:

```
{gravatar email="example@example.com" size="60" rating="X" assign="gravatarURL" default="http://www.example.com/default_gravatar.jpg"}

<img src="{$gravatarURL}" height="60" width="60">
```